# Only reload this form or div on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

My code works fine. It submits data without reloading.

But I want to reload only this form or this div as usual on submit.

In short, I want to submit this form like it happens with type = "submit". I don't want to prevent the load with js anymore but load only this form not other divs or the whole page.

What should I write here?

```
.done(function(data){
//reload div or form only         
})
```

```html
<div id="reply-box">

<div class="form-group">

<form action="" method="post" id="reply"  enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width: 85%;"  >
<div class="input-group">


<input type="file" name="image2" class="file" id="imgInp"/>

<span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="browse btn btn-primary input-md" type="button" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>I</button>
      </span>
<input   type="text" placeholder="say something" class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" required/><br/>

<span class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" >submit</button>
 </span>
 
 </div>
 <div>
 <img id="blah" src="/final/images/blank.jpg"   style=" width:7%; float:left; " />
 </div>
</form>

</div>
  


  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
 
 // submit form using $.ajax() method
 
 $('#reply').submit(function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
  
  $.ajax({
   url: 'reply.php?slug=<?=$page_id?>',
   type: 'POST',
   
  data:  new FormData(this),
   contentType: false,
         cache: false,
   processData:false,
  
  })
  .done(function(data){
  
      // here i want to refresh only the form or the div like normally happens on submit
  
   
  })
  .fail(function(){
   alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...'); 
  });
 });
 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried iframe?
Create a separate page for the form and load it on your main page with iframe.

More info at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: In general `iframe` is not used for a form.

Answer (score 0):

The *replacing* part is easy:

```
$('#reply').html(data);
```

Assuming that the server returns the same HTML markup.

*However*, there might be another problem, with event binding - all events bound to the elements that are being replaced will be gone. So you have couple of options:

**Extract things into functions**

This is fairly self explanatory: extract everything into a separate function, so you could call it recursively. So move this part:

```
$('#reply').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //
    // [...]
});
```

Into a separate block:

```
function bindMyAwesomeSubmit() {
    $('#reply').off('submit.mynamespace').on('submit.mynamespace', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //
        // [...]
        $.ajax()
        .done(function(data){
            $('#reply').html(data);
            bindMyAwesomeSubmit();
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(bindMyAwesomeSubmit);
```

(we also take care of unbinding events to prevent memory leaks).

**Use event delegation**

The other option would be to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which means that you actually bind the events to a higher element rather than the form.

This basically means that instead of `$('form').submit()` you will use a different way:

```
$('body').on('submit', 'my-form', callback)
```

(`body` is used as an example, just use the closest parent that is not chaniging.